# Does Java GAE UrlFetch support HTTP PUT?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http-post, urlfetch, http-put

How do I do an HTTP PUT request using the UrlFetch service for Google App Engine's Java runtime?

The following code in my application will send a POST request:

```
URL url = ...;
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(MAX_TIMEOUT); // Maximum allowable timeout on GAE of 60 seconds
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
OutputStreamWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), Charset.forName("utf-8"));
    writer.write(jsonContent);
} finally {
    if (writer != null)
        writer.close();
    }
}
InputStream inStream = null;
E response = null;   // Unmarshalled using Jackson
try {
    inStream = conn.getInputStream();
    if (status != 204) { // NO CONTENT => No need to use Jackson to deserialize!
        response = mapper.readValue(inStream, typeRef);
    }
} finally {
    if (inStream != null) {
        inStream.close();
    }
}
```

I try doing the same as `POST` for `PUT`, but I keep on getting a *405* HTTP error for Method Not Allowed. Thanks for the help.

**Reference:** https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview

Unfortunately, GAE Java doesn't have as good of documentation as Python's version of GAE URL fetch(https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview). Anyone from Google wanna say why?

Comment: **NOTE:** `typeRef` is a TypeReference instance, `mapper` is an ObjectMapper instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code works. The `HTTP 405` you are seeing is coming from the server you're contacting (not all services support `PUT`). You can try using `curl` to hit the URL if you'd like confirmation that it's not your code at fault:

```
curl -X PUT -d "foo=bar" http://your_site.com/path/to/your/resource
```

Comment: just for general knowledge...if I use my above code with `conn.setRequestMethod("PUT")` and I try to read from a *non-existent* URL, I never get a 404 but rather a 405. Is this normal behaviour?